# What's the best, most unique (and uneditable) hardware id or key for each computer?

Tags: authentication, hardware

I'm a C# programmer and I'm looking for the best way to "know" what hardware is running my software.  What is the best uneditable and unique "hardware id" in each computer?

Comment: In general, I believe none exists.

Comment: Ben - as Anti-weakpasswords says, nothing about your PC hardware is an uneditable hardware id. Closed as this isn't really a security question, and does not have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is "uneditable"; what science can create, science can replicate with sufficient funding and time, particularly with a sample.

The closest you're going to reasonably get is a cryptographic dongle, something like a [smartcard](https://www.netrust.net/partners/technologypartners.php) you provide with your software, after you've generated keys on said smartcard prior to shipment.  If you get a [FIPS 140-2 Validated](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm) module which has an Overall Level of 4, that's the best I'm aware of within the United States.

You may not know what hardware is actually running your software, but you'll have a resonable amount of certainty that whatever's checking in via

- Server sends app a cryptographically random message
- App signs message with smartcard's private key

  - ECC 256 bit or higher, or RSA 2048 bit or higher
  - which you'd generated before you shipped the card
- App sends signature to your server
- Your server validates the signature against that smartcard's private key

does, in fact, have the smartcard readily available to them.

You'll need to work out how to supply replacement cards, of course.

And you'll need to spend some money.  The cheap version of this uses someting like a [yubico product](https://www.yubico.com/) and foregoes FIPS certification, which at higher levels includes physical protections against subtle, hidden tampering (for instance, filling the interior with strong glue so it's very difficult to open it up, change it, and put it together again without leaving signs).